# Apache sends script from cgi-bin directory as plain text

Tags: apache, cgi, freebsd

This is on FreeBSD 11.3, with Apache 2.4 freshly installed via pkg.

As the minimal possible test of CGI, I'm trying to get the test-cgi script distributed as part of the Apache package for FreeBSD to run. (Serving static HTML pages works fine.)

I'm using the default directories, so the cgi-bin directory is /usr/local/www/apache24/cgi-bin. I have put a shebang for /bin/sh into the test-cgi file, and I have set the protection of the test-cgi file to 755. I can run the test-cgi file from the command line.

I have started Apache running.

I have checked that the config points the script alias directory to the right place:

`ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/www/apache24/cgi-bin/"`

I have checked the Directory block in the config for that directory and even tried adding some things (which didn't help):

```
<Directory "/usr/local/www/apache24/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When I put the URL for that script into my browser, I get the source file for the script as text, rather than the output from running the script. That source includes the shebang line I added, which confirms that the URL points to the file on the server that I expect it to.

I've read many articles, all of which suggest things I've checked and have correct.  (I've been running Apache since I stopped running the NCSA web server, back in the day; but the last decade I haven't been doing clean installs on systems I have root on mostly, so I'm in danger of having out-of-date knowledge, sometimes worse than ignorance.)

No errors are logged when this happens. In the access log, I get a 304 error followed by a 200:

```
192.168.1.14 - - [15/Feb/2022:17:45:42 -0600] "GET /cgi-bin/test-cgi HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.168.1.14 - - [15/Feb/2022:18:00:24 -0600] "GET /cgi-bin/test-cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 1269
```

That ought to mean something useful, I would think? The 304 is a "not modified" status, which should be returned on a conditional request. This is probably somehow relevant?  If I update the file timestamp it doesn't change this, though.

This has got to be something *really* simple, perhaps even stupid, that I'm overlooking. Would somebody please point out what precise stupid thing it is?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! In the default config the `LoadModule` commands for `cgi_module` and `cgid_module` were commented out.

Uncommenting them (only one is actually loaded due to surrounding `<ifModule>` code) got the CGI working normally.